# Draggable object doesnt work inside of listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I wanted to create simple chatting application to learn my way around flutter. I got stuck with draggable. When I put it as a widget inside listview (and listview.builder) the feedback is for some reason always aligned on the left side.

```
class Message{
 final int messageId;
 final int authorId;
 String text;

 Message({required this.messageId, required this.text, required this.authorId});

}

class Chat{
  String name;
  List<Message> messages = [];
  Chat({required this.name});
}

class MessageTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function function;
  const MessageTextField({super.key, required this.function});

  @override
  State<MessageTextField> createState() => _MessageTextFieldState();
}

class _MessageTextFieldState extends State<MessageTextField> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: 
              TextField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Message',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  filled: true
                ),
                obscureText: false,
              )
            ),
            IconButton(
            onPressed:()=>{widget.function(controller.text)}, 
            icon: const Icon(Icons.telegram))
          ],);
  }
}


class MessageDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final Message message;
  const MessageDisplay({super.key, required this.message});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      //alignment: message.authorId == 0 ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
          child:Text(message.text),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ResponsiveMessageDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final Message message;
  const ResponsiveMessageDisplay({super.key, required this.message});
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // MessageDisplay md = MessageDisplay(message: message);
    return 
    Draggable( 
      feedback: MessageDisplay(message: message),
      child: MessageDisplay(message: message,)
    );
  }
}

class ChatEnvironment extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatEnvironment({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChatEnvironment> createState() => _ChatEnvironmentState();
}

class _ChatEnvironmentState extends State<ChatEnvironment> {

  Chat chat = Chat(name:'Maty');

  void addMessage(String text){
    chat.messages.add(Message(text: text, messageId: 8, authorId: 0));
    setState(() {
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child:
        ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)// => ResponsiveMessageDisplay(message: chat.messages[index]) ,
          {
            try {
              return ResponsiveMessageDisplay(message: chat.messages[index]);
            }
            on RangeError{
              return MessageDisplay(message: Message(messageId: 0, text: "Message $index", authorId: 0));
            }
          }
          // children: [
          // for (Message message in chat.messages)
          //   ResponsiveMessageDisplay(message: message)
          // ],
        )),
        MessageTextField(function: addMessage)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The whole logic is obviously not finished but that is not the point.[image]
The "jou" on left appears as I click on its right counterpart. I have no idea why. I tried changing the anchor strategy and did not work.

Comment: Sorry about the big image, i did not figure out how to make it smaller

Comment: To resize images, you can see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052/1423447). But I think this one is fine

Comment: Can you include what the expected behavior looks like?